# Creating a View for each table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, view

We use a code generator to specify our Entity model in XML, and this also generates our database DDL script.  Because of this, trying to do anything fancy or custom in a table, especially with a relationship to another table, is cumbersome as it involves lots of effort to change how the generator works, as well as risk because of the potential breadth of impact.

One train of thought to make this easier in the future, is to have the code generator create a view for every table and then have all basic calls query from the views instead of the tables.  This would allow devs to update the view with custom columns without having to touch the table itself or the code generator.

My question is this: Is there a common pattern for implementing something like this (bypassing basically every table in the DB in favour of a view in a 1:1 relationship), or any common pitfalls for implementing a database in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using views for interfacing to the database is actually relatively common and at least a good practice.

The usual reason is to isolate users from underlying changes to the database.  The columns can keep the database "backwards" compatible in many cases, preventing harm to applications.

Your use is a little more iffy.  Apparently, you are using a tool that doesn't fully meet the needs of your development.  Generating the views -- while not a bad idea at all -- is to work around other problems.  My main concern would be whether you have other outstanding issues that are not so easily solved.

Comment: OK, great thanks.  The tool is definitely limited but at this point (at least for now) it's easier to work around it than to modify it.
As such, i'm looking for something that, even though it's a work-around, should still be a valid direction to go